# Hows does Unix Binary Exucutables bypass screen time

Tags: macos

I like to play minecraft alot so I placed a restriction for 3 hours only for my to play it for the entire day! I did some research this weird bypass only happens on Unix Binary Executables. So my question is why does this not happen to google if they are run with these files.